# Create a Block with data from database in Sulu

Tags: sulu

I need to build a block with data from (Symfony) Entity.

For example a carousel with last 3 item/record from database.

This block can appear in more than just a page.

I know that I can use a custom controller but is that the best technical choice ?

Do i need "Smart content" ? Read [the doc](https://docs.sulu.io/en/2.2/book/smart-content.html) but it's not clear

How i can do that ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Using a twig extension or a controller would definitely be the easiest way, because no sulu knowledge is required for that.

But the `sulu` way of solving that problem would be a custom `SmartContentDataProvider`. There are two main advantages of this method:

- The content editor can further filter the result (in your case probably sorting and limiting)
- The result is also displayed in the admin interface (Otherwise it would just be shown in the preview)

Our community is usually using our [Slack channel](https://sulu.io/services-and-support) or [GitHub Discussions](https://github.com/sulu/sulu/discussions) for support questions. Your questions will probably be answered a lot faster there, because there we can better track them.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! Joining Slack to investigate ....